# Online QFT video lectures

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations

I'm aware of Sidney Coleman's 1975/76 sequence of [54 lectures](http://www.physics.harvard.edu/about/Phys253.html) on Quantum Field Theory. Are there any other high-quality QFT lecture series available online?

Comment: [Notes from Sidney Coleman's Physics 253a](http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.5013).

Answer (score 29):

The Perimeter Institute has recorded all the courses of their one-year Master's in Theoretical Physics. The courses are given by professors and lecturers from different universities.

For a full list of the courses they recorded in 2010/w011 go to [Pirsa.org](http://pirsa.org/), and under "4. Collections" select "Course" and "2010". The courses are labeled by the tag "10/11 PSI". (I couldnt find a decent link which neatly lists all the courses)

You'll find multiple courses on QM, QFT, string theory, Beyond the standard Model, General Relativity, condensed matter physics, Quantum Information and many more. The format is also very neat. The Flash presentation is a recording of the class in low-quality, combined with decent photos of the blackboard.

Here are some direct links:

[QFT part I -- by K. Zarembo](http://pirsa.org/C10030)

[QFT part II --  by F. David](http://pirsa.org/C10033)

Also check out the courses given in 09/11 (search for "2009" instead), where the curriculum was a bit different (also different lecturers). You have for instance David Tong from Cambridge who gives an introductary course on QFT.

[QFT part I -- by D. Tong](http://pirsa.org/C09033)

(part II was also given by F. David)

The site also has a large collection of recorded seminars.

Comment: Stanford also have a number of freely available lecture courses. Susskind has posted courses on   CLASSICAL MECHANICS
  QUANTUM MECHANICS, SPECIAL RELATIVITY, GENERAL RELATIVITY, COSMOLOGY, STATISTICAL MECHANICS, QUANTUM ENTANGLEMENT 1, QUANTUM ENTANGLEMENT 2, QUANTUM ENTANGLEMENT 3, BASIC PARTICLE PHYSICS, and THE STANDARD MODEL. Whilst none of these are specically QFT, you'll probably find th eStandard Model ones useful. http://www.newpackettech.com/Resources/Susskind/PHY30_2B/NewRevolutionsInParticlePhysics_TheStandardModel.htm

Answer (score 4):

... and from Lenny Susskind too there is

http://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/supersymmetry-grand-unification/id384233338

and

http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=202191442DB1B300

and this new course

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZ-ElsvYKyo&feature=relmfu

Answer (score 3):

### CERN Lectures

--

Lecturer: **Herman Nicolai**
Title: Quantum field theory
Year: 1997

Abstract: The lectures are intended to provide an introduction to Quantum Field Theory at an elementary level. In particular, the following topics will be treated: 1, Basic principle of QFT; 2, Representation theory of the Poincaré group; 3, The free scalar field; 4, The free Dirac field 5, Interacting field theories; 6, Supersymmetry; 7, S-Matrix. The emphasis will be more on general concepts than on specific applications. Therefore, for most of the lectures, only a knowledge of quantum mechanics and special relativity will be assumed.

Link: http://cds.cern.ch/record/338008/

--

Lecturer: **Erik Verlinde**
Title: Introduction to quantum field theory
Year: 1998

Abstract: In these lectures the basic concepts of quantum field theory are introduced. Topics that will be discussed are: the quantization of fields; Scattering amplitudes and cross sections; Feynman diagrams; Lagrangian field theory; Quantum electrodynamics; Gauge invariance and renormalization.

Link: http://cds.cern.ch/record/387599?ln=en

Comment: these cern lecture videos seem to be broken at the time of this comment.

Answer (score 3):

Although the recordings of lectures from the *Perimeter Institute* has been done some years now, the Perimeter Institute launched the **PSI Online** program in **2018**, which as of now contains three full courses (lecture videos + problem sets), two in Quantum Field Theory and one in advanced Condensed Matter physics.

An overview of PSI Online can be found in the following link:
https://www.perimeterinstitute.ca/training/psi-masters-program/psi-online

Comment: that sounds awesome! but the link no longer works, so I update the link, hope you dont mind!

Answer (score 3):

As the world moved online in the time of this pandemic, we got a gem.

Quantum Field Theory 1 (QFT-1) by Ashoke Sen

Video Lectures: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLt4li39O1V1WGB_mI3S7ia1GbnJLOf8t1

Lecture Notes: [https://www.hri.res.in/~sen/QFT1_lectures.pdf](https://www.hri.res.in/%7Esen/QFT1_lectures.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

For the beginner, there is a great series of lectures by Anthony Zee, author of *Field Theory in a Nutshell*, available from ASTI here:http://www.asti.ac.za/lectures.php. Some of the other lectures are quite good as well.

Comment: Link to Zee's home page: http://www.kitp.ucsb.edu/members/PM/zee/QuantumFieldTh.html

Answer (score 2):

Susskind's *The Theoretical Minimum* now has introduction to Quantum Field Theory (although the title is "Advanced Quantum Mechanics):

https://theoreticalminimum.com/courses/advanced-quantum-mechanics/2013/fall

Answer (score 1):

http://indico.cern.ch/categoryDisplay.py?categId=72

The INDICO servers by CERN have **tons** of video lectures on many different topics, related to particle physics and cosmology.

Comment: I can find pdf slides but no video?

Answer (score 0):

I have collected together some learning resources on theoretical physics on my web page:

https://www.paulbooker.co.uk/theoretical-physics/

Comment: Resource recommendation answers should discuss the presentation style, contents and similar characteristics instead of just giving a list, as discussed [in this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-resource-recommendations-allowed/4698#4698). Also, avoid answers that are entirely based on a link, since it might break in the future and doesn't really add to the site. See [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) for more on this

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but not interested.