# How should be the course of learning for Particle Physics?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, resource-recommendations, education

I'm a senior high school student. I want to learn particle physics as a hobby. I did some research about it ,and I learned that I should learn Quantum Field Theory for entering Particle Physics. QFT needs some high degree math. How can be a possible learning path in math/physics for me?

Comment: Try this : http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/theorist.html

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/226418/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The "Preface for Students" to Srednicki's QFT textbook has a list of equations that you should understand before even considering starting: https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/ms-qft-DRAFT.pdf

Comment: You can learn about the elementary particles, their properties, their interactions, the history of their discovery, and how particle accelerators and detectors work without necessarily learning *any* quantum field theory. This will probably be much more enjoyable and productive than trying to learn QFT without the necessary background in higher mathematics. If you want to start to understand what QFT is about, read Feynman’s *[QED: The Strange Theory of Light and Matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QED:_The_Strange_Theory_of_Light_and_Matter)* which is for the general reader.