# Self Understanding the technical concepts of Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, education

So I have always been passionate in physics but recently I began to take a greater interest in learning more than the curriculum of my age. I have a significant theoretical understanding of quantum physics and mechanics yet my technical ( as in terms, constants and formulating equations) knowledge is far from sufficient with me struggling to understand what the terms mean in each equation. Some tips on where to expand my technical knowledge is what I am asking for please.

Comment: "I have a significant theoretical understanding of quantum physics and mechanics yet my technical [...] knowledge is far from sufficient with me struggling to understand what the terms mean in each equation"--this sound completely contradictory.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/226418/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 5):

> I have a significant theoretical understanding of quantum physics and mechanics yet my technical ( as in terms, constants and formulating equations) knowledge is far from sufficient with me struggling to understand what the terms mean in each equation.

If you don't understand the equations you don't understand quantum mechanics. My recommendation would be that you learn QM well and then ask what to do next. There are textbooks you can read like "Introduction to Quantum Mechanics" by Griffiths and Schroeter:

https://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Quantum-Mechanics-David-Griffiths/dp/1107189632/

There isn't much point in you trying to learn QFT until you have a solid understanding of quantum mechanics.

Comment: Thank you very much