# Thermal/finite temperature quantum field theory: online lectures and best books

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, temperature, resource-recommendations

There is nice [theme](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10021/online-qft-video-lectures) about online lectures on QFT. I would like to know about any online lectures on **thermal/finite temperature QFT**. Also, I would like to know about some of the best books on thermal/finite temperature QFT.

I know about:

1. M. Le Bellac, Thermal Field Theory, Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, New York, Melbourne, 1996.
2. J. I. Kapusta and C. Gale, Finite-Temperature Field Theory; Principles and Applications, Cambridge University Press, 2 ed., 2006.
3. M. Laine and A. Vuorinen, Basics of Thermal Field Theory, vol. 925 of Lecture Notes in Physics, 2016.

Maybe you know about other good books?

Answer (score 1):

Lectures of Prof. Ashok Sen on Thermal Field Theory https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLB5CVZSR7aDyWsnElpjiU8ahQ0W8uDdCe might be valuable, which are based on the book of M. Laine and A. Vuorinen, Basics of Thermal Field Theory, vol. 925 of Lecture Notes in Physics, 2016.

Comment: Could you add details on the style, content, and prerequisites of the book, as requested in the banner?

Answer (score 1):

May be Altland & Ben Simons will be interesting for you. This book covers a wide range of topics from condensed matter.

Answer (score 1):

Negele & Orland is a good book for the basics. Covers the standard formalism in great detail, with all the derivations step by step. It has very few applications and actual calculations though.

Altland & Simons has a wide range of problems,calculations and covers some more advanced topics, although often glosses over the details.

Prerequisites for both: quantum mechanics and thermodynamics. The formalism of second quantization is introduced in the books.

Answer (score 1):

Ashok Das' book Finite Temperature Field Theory is a nice book as an introduction to the topic. Very basic and easy to understand.